# How can I spread a modulated signal over walsh code

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to confirm if spreading signal by using walsh code in MATLAB is right or no,

Suppose I'm using QAM modulation, so I need to spread the signal over walsh code, is the below step is right:

```
M = 4;
alphabit = modem.qammod('M',  M ) ;             %QAM modulation
mod = transpose(modulate( alphabit , (0:M-1)));
avg = mod'*mod / M ;                % average power of constellation points
mod = mod / sqrt(avg);              % to make E[x^t x ] = 1 
H = hadamard(4);   % The walsh code generation 
H_use = H(:,2);  %using the second column for spreading. 
S_coded = kron(mod,H_use);  % Spread the modulated data mod over the walsh code
```

My question is about the last step, is that right how we spread the modulated signal? ..